# Is an OS compiled every time it boots?

Tags: compiler, operating-systems, kernel

Is an OS compiled every time it boots, or is it compiled once and the result used every time the OS is (re)booted?

When users change settings, is the compiled kernel modified at all?

If I am the one writing the OS, would I compile it and then users install it without need for compilation?

Comment: no, yes, no . your question is confusing

Comment:  Sorry I cant ask it in another way

Comment: @Y.R. Oh, but I can.

Comment: Your question is technically "does there exist any OS that is compiled each time it boots?" And I can technically make the answer yes just by writing a script to recompile any kernel for which I have the source before starting it in a VM. So long as I never forget to recompile before launching, that is. Is this useful information? Is it really the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: @Useless I think that's a ridiculously narrow way of reading the question, and it's perfectly normal to say "does X do Y?" meaning "do most normal instances of X do Y?", not "does there exist somewhere in the universe an X that does Y?"

Comment: Well, it's a very odd question, so I don't think it's unreasonable to nudge OP to add what prompted the question, or whether they have some particular OS in mind, or why the idea even occurred to them. Since the only two answers are "not normally" and "that depends", it could probably benefit from that clarity.

Answer (score 3):

> Is an OS compiled every time it boots?

Not normally.

> Or is it compiled once and is the result used each time the OS is (re)booted?

Usually.

> When users change any setting, is the compiled kernel modified after all?

Depends on the setting.

Compiling is not part of booting. It’s part of development. To compile you typically need to already have booted.

When you compile you turn source code into machine code. Once you have machine code you can run it over and over. When you boot to an OS that’s what you’re doing.

So if you wanted to, you could recompile before rebooting. But doing that every time, even when you haven’t changed the source, is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. For Windows, you can't even have source code to compile, because it's closed-source. For Linux, do you have any idea how long it takes to compile the Linux kernel using GCC? And that's just the kernel. Plus, most compilers can't even run on bare metal, they require an OS to function. Francis Bellard's Tiny C Compiler is capable actually capable of compiling the Linux Kernel running on bare metal and it takes it 15 seconds to compile it ( https://bellard.org/tcc/tccboot.html ), but it produces vastly inferior assembly code.

Comment: I dont want to compile any os. I want to write an os and I want to know compile on system for once or for all boots

Comment: @Y.R You compile it for all boots, of course. If you don't know that, you have a lot to learn before you can successfully write an OS.

Comment: For example windows,  compiles its kernel on all boots????

Comment: "Absolutely not. For Windows, you can't even have source code to compile, because it's closed-source." – Your conclusion doesn't follow from your assumption. Just because Windows has a proprietary license, doesn't mean they can't ship source code. The reason Windows isn't compiled on boot is because it was designed that way, not because the license doesn't allow you to copy the source code.

Comment: @JorgWMittag I think it's reasonable to say that "closed source" means "can't even read the source", unless you have a better term that rules out your hypothetical scenario of shipping source code that you're not allowed to do anything with.

Comment: "do you have any idea how long it takes to compile the Linux kernel using GCC?" I'm guessing from the question that the answer on the OP's part would be "no", so you'd be better off telling them than using rhetorical questions. I know you mention one timing, but it's not really clear if you're saying that's fast or slow.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, compilation is the process of turning human-readable source code into machine-readable binary instructions. Once you have those instructions in place, you generally want to reuse them as much as possible, because executing something is much, much faster than compiling it. That's no different if the program you're compiling is a game, a word processor, or the kernel of an operating system - except that the bigger the program, the bigger the cost of recompiling it.

There are basically two reasons to recompile something:

- Because you've changed the source code to do something completely new.
- To optimise the binary program for a new situation, such as a different CPU instruction set.

Occasionally, these two things go hand in hand, because to squeeze the most performance out of something, you want to remove all decisions while it's running, and hard-code options in the source code before compiling.

This is probably where you've heard about kernels being recompiled: because the source code of the Linux kernel is freely available and designed in a particular way, you can recompile it with certain features that you don't need switched off, or certain options hard-coded. But that's something that will be done manually by expert users, not something that happens during the normal usage of a Linux system.

With Windows, the answer is even more clear cut: only Microsoft and a few people they've made specific arrangements with have the source code to their kernel, so only they can compile it. If you have a copy of Windows, what you have is the binaries they've compiled, and your PC just executes them.

Comment: "only Microsoft has the source code to their kernel, so only they can compile it" – That is not true, there are various ways you can get access to the source code. IBM has access to it because Windows NT started as a joint project, and they own partial copyrights. CPU vendors get access to it in order to port it to new architectures. Governments get access to it in order to review it for security flaws and backdoors. Operating Systems Researchers get access to it for studying, adapting, modifying, etc. E.g. the developers of Xen ported Windows to run natively on Xen. They weren't allowed to …

Comment: … redistributed the source code or the compiled binaries, and they weren't allowed to publish benchmark results, but they were allowed to run the compiled OS themselves, and write papers about it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Fair enough, I've edited to make clear that there may be some people outside MS who have it. The point stands that _normal users_ don't, so recompiling on boot or setting change is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Not normally. There are very minor things:

MacOS has highly optimised code for memset, memcpy, and atomic operations, which uses all the tricks in the book and is dependent on the processor. That code is copied at boot time into a fixed protected location, so these operations happen as fast as possible on your computer.

And there is OpenCL and OpenGL code, which will be compiled at runtime, specifically for the graphics card and the processors in your computer for optimal performance. So if you shut down the computer, swap graphics cards, and boot it again, there will be different code running for example to scroll the screen on your computer.

Comment: It was not my question answer 

Comment: my question is that if i write my own OS, I must compile it on my system, or When a user install it on him system, In installation It must be compiled? Or on each boot it must compile???

Comment: Read the first two words. That is 99% of your answer. And the rest is the missing percent.

Answer (score -1):

> Is an OS compiled every time it boots? Or is it compiled once and is the result used each time the OS is (re)booted?

That depends on the OS.

> When users change any setting, is the compiled kernel modified after all?

That depends on the OS. Depending on the OS, it also depends on the setting.

Comment: For example windows, what about it?

Comment: Windows doesn't even ship with a compiler by default. What would it compile itself with?

Comment: While pedantically correct, I'm not aware of any OS for which the answer would be anything other than "no", and even if some such OS exists, it would be a notable exception. It's like saying the answer to "do birds lay eggs?" is "it depends on the bird".

Comment: @IMSoP: For question #1, there was at least one Lisp OS. Also, SqueakNOS, I believe. For question #2, Linux. Changing the `VMSPLIT` config option, for example, requires recompiling the kernel.

Comment: Then with those examples, you might have a reasonable answer (although make sure you explain the difference between "requires recompiling" and "causes recompiling"). Just saying "it depends", with no further explanation, doesn't tell anybody anything.